# How can I get this overlay effect in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to do this effect in Jetpack Compose where it has like a kind of solid shadow. I've tried to overlap the button with a Box, but I can't get it because with the padding I can't make it stand out, it just makes it smaller.

[image]

This is my best try:

```kotlin
Box(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(92. dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16. dp))
        .background(JordyBlue)
        .padding(top = 10. dp)
    )

    Button(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16. dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Portage),
        modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(92. dp)
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "Continue",
            fontFamily = RobotoFamily,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            fontSize = 20. sp,
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@hanihashemi/implementing-custom-shadows-with-jetpack-compose-for-neumorphism-design-cd666887a642 does this help?

Comment: If you don't need it strictly be a Button you can check this answer. setting strokeWidth 0.dp and changing other params you can get same background colors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421266/how-to-draw-a-curved-border-on-the-bottom-of-a-button-in-android-compose/77421621#77421621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Canvas** for your custom button as below.

> Note: You can set `Size` as per your choice and `Height` of your
> choice

You need to define two rounded Rectangles one above another with size variation.

**Preview Of Code**
[image: preview]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.CornerRadius
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomButtonExample() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(80.dp)
    ) {
        val si = size.copy(height = size.height - 15)
        drawRoundRect(
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(35f, 35f),
            color = Color(0xFFA7A4F8),
            size = size
        )
        drawRoundRect(
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(35f, 35f),
            color = Color(0xFF8976EA),
            size = si
        )
    }

}
```